# Trying from past 4 days not able to fix the issue

Tags: loadrunner

Iam giving the excat LB values and RB values..But still iam facing an issue..Can anyone plz help me in this.Thanks in advanceError -26377: No match found for the requested.parameter "ViewState ". Check whether the requested boundaries exist in the response data. Also, if the data you want to save exceeds 10000000 bytes, use web_set_max_html_param_len to increase the parameter size[MsgId: MERR-26377]
Action.c(28): Notify: Saving Parameter "ViewState _count = 0".

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this can happen:

1. You are not receiving a valid page back with a valid viewstate which matches your LB and RB conditions.  This often happens when steps to check for positive expected results are not properly paired in the test code.  As a result the business process comes off the tracks prior to your page with the error, typically one to two pages prior, resulting in a 500 class page or a graceful error page (depending upon the robustness of the developer) when passing invalid data to the system.   You also might receive a zero byte page without any values you can track
2. Checking in the wrong location.   Correlation is very location sensitive, having to be paired with the precise request which generates the return values.   A mismatch in request pairing will result in a failure to find as the context is the next following request
3. As noted by the error, size can come into play.  This is probably the rarest of the conditions.  You appear to have set aside ~10MB for the match buffer.  This is a very very large amount as this buffer will need to be set aside for every single virtual user as the match buffer.   Essentially you have made your minimum virtual user size to be 10MB plus the value of any Viewstates which are captured and not cleaned or reused to the end of your business process.   If the value of your state management variables exceeds this value, or is anywhere near this value, then you have found your first defect.  This will result in poor performance due to a high dependency on the network on both the client and the server end to sustain the load from the state management variables.   This would also provide insight to your developers who are throwing everything by default into state instead of considering very carefully just the items that are essential to be in state.   I would recommend that you consider trimming this value to the essential level for capture or else you will pay a high price on your virtual user resource use on your load generators.   Keep in mind that for most versions of LoadRunner you are dealing with only a 32-bit address space, 4GB, which has to be shared with the operating system and anything else which is running on the host. Large footprint virtual users can overwhelm the load generator quite quickly

Comment: when i run with 1 vuser for the first time sometime i get no 
error, once i got no error if i re-run it again, with the same 1 
vuser i get same error message. What is missing here!! I tried 
with 2 vuser, sometime it pass sometime it gives error. What can 
I change in my scripts

Comment: use the manual correlation model.   Record twice with the same user credentials.  Compare the changes.   Makes sure you have handled all of the dynamic bits and you are checking for positive expected results.   Then record a third time with different credentials.  This will likely expose additional items that need to be addressed on a dynamic basis.

Comment: i have done the same..when i done the replay my application is not able to login.Its throwing me error..Internal server error.please contact the system administartor..I have checked in the run_time_viewer.

Comment: Internal Server Error means that you are handing it bad data which is out of context with the existing state of the application/server.  When you have developers who are not handling errors well you will get a 500 for this, otherwise you will receive a cleaner page.   In any case you are doing something in your test code which your server deems to be unacceptable.